# Is there a way to remove invalid characters in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to read an Excel file with pandas in python.
My Code is as simple as this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(open("excel.xlsx"),encoding='utf-8')
```

But I get the following error after running the script:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 16: character maps to <undefined>`

It looks like there is at least one character that is 'invalid' in my excel file.
I have tried to save the Excel file with a different name or and tried some other encodings that were suggested in other SO threads. But nothing resolved this issue.
How can i get rid of those characters in my Excel file?

Comment: Shouldn't the encoding be `utf-8` and not `utf=8`?

Comment: Yes for sure that was a typo, with `utf-8` and also `utf-8-sig` as suggested below, I get the exact same error

Comment: Have you tried using cp850?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xlsx file is a binary file, while open will try to read it as a text file and pass this on to read_excel, hence this fails to read it. Instead, use

```
data = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", encoding='utf-8')
```

If you want to use open (which is not needed in this case, as pandas automatically opens the file for you), you can do

```
data = pd.read_excel(open("excel.xlsx", mode='rb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ori6151 is correct with the encoding needing to be "utf-8", also "utf-8-sig" works well.

I had to use the encoding "cp850" which stopped this error for me. It of course depends on what the character is it can't decode.